# Почему здесь нужен overflow: auto?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, style, overflow

В книге было написано, что если в элементе-контейнере находятся только плавающие элементы, то некоторые браузеры будут воспринимать их так, будто они имеют высоту в 0 пикселов. Для решения этой проблемы элементу контейнеру нужно добавить свойство overflow со значением auto.
Но далее приведён пример из книги, в котором элементу с идентификатором content применено свойство overflow со значением, хотя в этом элементе-контейнере лишь несколько элементов являются плавающими (div'ы с идентификаторами column1, column2, column3). И без overflow: auto действительно в этом примере страница будет отображаться некорректно.

Чтобы понять, что конкретно не так работает, запустите мой код. А затем раскомментируйте overflow: auto и запустите ещё раз и вы увидите как это должно работать. 
Мой вопрос заключается в следующем:  почему в этом примере нужен overflow: auto?

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  /*overflow: auto;*/
}

#nav,
#characteristic,
#footer {
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

#column1,
#column2,
#column3 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: efefef;
}

#characteristic,
.article {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Логотип</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Домой</li>
      <li>Товары</li>
      <li>Услуги</li>
      <li>О нас</li>
      <li>Контакты</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="characteristic">
      <p>Характеристики</p>
    </div>
    <div id="column1" class="article">
      <p>Колонка1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="column2" class="article">
      <p>Колонка2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="column3" class="article">
      <p>Колонка3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Собственность 2019</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Наверное для того, что бы исключить схлопывание `margin`. Не стоит задавать одинаковых вопросов.

Comment: По сути ту не должно быть схлопывания. Оно происходит при других обстоятельствах. Но если я не прав, прошу объясните пожалуйста почему :) А на тот вопрос я не получил исчерпывающего ответа, поэтому создал другой. Может быть тут найду ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Схлопывание будет, так как у дочернего элемента есть `margin-top` и только благодаря `overflow: auto` на родительском элементе не происходит схлопавыние, так же к таким свойствам можно отнести `float`, `position: absolute`, `display: inline-block` и др.

Подробней можете почитать [здесь](https://jonathan-harrell.com/whats-the-deal-with-margin-collapse/).

---

В примере видно, что между первыми двумя блоками происходит схлопывание и так же происходит схлопывание дочернего и родительского элемента, поэтому размер `margin` между ними равен `margin-top` дочернего элемента.

Во втором мы используем `oveflow: auto` на род. элементе, что предотвращает схлопывание между родительским(`container`) и дочерним элементом(`block`). Но, остается схлопывание между основными блоками(`container`).

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.container+.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.block {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  </div>

  <div class="container overflow">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPD.** Ваши `float` элементы выпадают из родительского блока(потока) из за этого высота `content` блока равна блоку без `float`, если бы его не было высота родителя была бы равна `0`. Поэтому происходит накладывание блоков с `float` на `footer`, так как высота блока `content` меньше, чем контент этого блока.

Что бы избежать этого с `float` в основном используют `clearfix` для отмены "обтекания". Так же обнулить `float` можно с помощью `display: inline-block`, `oveflow: hidden`(как в вашем примере) и другими свойствами.

```
.clearfix::after {
   display: table;
   clear: both;
   content: ""
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это я итак знал) Я спрашиваю другое)) Я немного уточнил и дополнил вопрос, возможно так будет понятнее, что конкретно я имел в виду =)

Comment: @JustLearn, обновил ответ.

Comment: "Ваши float элементы выпадают из родительского блока(потока) из за этого высота content блока равна блоку без float, если бы его не было высота родителя была бы равна 0". Под "если бы его не было, высота родителя была бы равна 0" вы имеете в виду, что если бы не было блоков с float, то content имел бы высоту 0? Я просто не совсем понял. И ещё вопрос: "Ваши float элементы выпадают из родительского блока(потока) из за этого высота content блока равна блоку без float" float элементы всегда выпадают из потока?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, но разъясните пожалуйста некоторые моменты :)

Comment: @JustLearn, 
1. В вашем примере помимо блоков с флоат есть обычный блок `characteristic`, из за этого высота блока `content = characteristic`. Если убрать блок `characteristic`, то высота `content` будет равна `0`.
2.Да, если не использовать свойства предотвращающие это.
p.s. Если хотите полностью понять механизм работы `float` лучше прочитайте о нем в стандарте.

Comment: Спасибо, я вроде понял)